# Problems with starting Telegram bot

Tags: flask, python-requests, openssl, pythonanywhere, py-telegram-bot-api

I'm trying to deploy my telegram-bot on PythonAnywhere. It has worked fine with the free account but there are some troubles with the paid one. I'm getting "**OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_record', 'decryption failed or bad record mac')]**" messages in Error logs (accordingly bot works wrong). How can I solve it?
I'm using **python3.7** + **pyTelegramBotAPI** + **flask**

Code example for error reproducing:

```
# coding=utf-8
import telebot
import flask
import time


token = 'bot_token'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token, threaded=False)

WEBHOOK_HOST = '*userName*.pythonanywhere.com'
WEBHOOK_URL_BASE = "https://%s" % (WEBHOOK_HOST)
WEBHOOK_URL_PATH = "/%s/" % (token)

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

# Process webhook calls
@app.route(WEBHOOK_URL_PATH, methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
    if flask.request.headers.get('content-type') == 'application/json':
        json_string = flask.request.get_data().decode('utf-8')
        update = telebot.types.Update.de_json(json_string)
        bot.process_new_updates([update])
        return ''
    else:
        flask.abort(403)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def handle_start_help(message):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Hello, my friend")

bot.remove_webhook()
time.sleep(0.1)
bot.set_webhook(url=WEBHOOK_URL_BASE + WEBHOOK_URL_PATH)
```

Full error trace:

```
2018-10-30 12:40:33,351: Exception on /*token*/ [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/kleratoni/bot/bot/Main.py", line 90, in webhook
    bot.process_new_updates([update])
  File "/home/*accountName*/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 326, in process_new_updates
    self.process_new_callback_query(new_callback_querys)
  File "/home/*accountName*/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 354, in process_new_callback_query
    self._notify_command_handlers(self.callback_query_handlers, new_callback_querys)
  File "/home/*accountName*/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 1490, in _notify_command_handlers
    self._exec_task(message_handler['function'], message)
  File "/home/*accountName*/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 464, in _exec_task
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/*accountName*/bot/bot/Main.py", line 535, in callback_inline
    MainMenuActions.BetMenu_BackButton(call.message, bot, db)
  File "/home/*accountName*/bot/bot/MainMenuActions.py", line 130, in BetMenu_BackButton
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=config.StringContent["StartPlayWords"], reply_markup=keyborads.keyboardMainmenu)
  File "/home/*accountName*/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 598, in send_message
    reply_markup, parse_mode, disable_notification))
  File "/home/*accountName*/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/telebot/apihelper.py", line 140, in send_message
    return _make_request(token, method_url, params=payload, method='post')
  File "/home/*accountName*/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/telebot/apihelper.py", line 54, in _make_request
    timeout=(connect_timeout, read_timeout), proxies=proxy)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 512, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 622, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 445, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 384, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 2, in raise_from
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 380, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1321, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 296, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 257, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 300, in recv_into
    return self.recv_into(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 285, in recv_into
    return self.connection.recv_into(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1814, in recv_into
    self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1639, in _raise_ssl_error
    _raise_current_error()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/_util.py", line 54, in exception_from_error_queue
    raise exception_type(errors)
OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_record', 'decryption failed or bad record mac')]
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

I had a same error and I fixed like this

```py
token = 'bot_token'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token, threaded=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

From an issue on the pyTelegramBotAPI github repo, it looks like it's an incompatibility between the version of requests you're using and the version of OpenSSL you're using. Try using requests 2.10.0 instead.

Comment: I've tested it a lot. It doesn't helped. Just the error text has change to:  

**requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC] decryption failed or bad record mac (_ssl.c:2281)**  
I've downgraded to the "Beginner" account and it works fine. But I need more "CPU time" and disk free space.

Comment: when you say that it works when you downgrade but not when you upgrade- what changes have you made when you upgrade. eg: are you now using your own custom domain  name?

Comment: @conrad, if i am not mistaken, nothing had changed except number of uWSGI workers. I have no custom domain for my project on Pythonanywhere, I have no any other python modules.

Comment: i would try running everything from within a virtualenv and also making sure that you have reloaded your webapp etc in between changes. this definitely sounds like that requests version / package version compatibility issue